# React router difference between render and children prop

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I wanted to understand the exact differences between the 2 ways of writing React `<Route />` i.e. one with "render" and other with "children" prop;

```
// With "render"
    <Route
          path={route.path}
          render={props => (
            // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
            <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />
          )}
        />

// With "children"
    <Route
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            children={props => <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />}
          />
```

Also, with the 2nd use case (i.e. with "children"), what difference does it make when exact property is true v/s false ?

Comment: I believe [reading render props documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#:~:text=The%20term%20%E2%80%9Crender%20prop%E2%80%9D%20refers,implementing%20its%20own%20render%20logic.) might help clearify the situation if you haven't already

Comment: You can avoid unexpected components when using `children` prop by wrapping `<Route>` by `<Switch>` to only render when there is a match. Check demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-children-r33rs?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 4):

From the docs of

[`React Router's render function`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)

> This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above.Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the `location matches`

And

[`React Router's children function`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/children-func)

> Sometimes you need to render whether the `path matches the location or not`. In these cases, you can use the function children prop. It works exactly like render except that it gets called whether there is a `match or not`.

The main difference as per what I understand is that when we pass a component as `children` prop then that component will get rendered even if the location `matches or not`.

I have created a sample app in order to simulate the same, [here is the app](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-render-children-kwl3i?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks a lot...So seems like the component passed to "children" is rendered to the screen always irrespective of the current path user is on? 

Also with the "children" prop, does the value of "exact" attribute affect this rendering in any way ?

Comment: Yes, `children` will be rendered always irrespective of path matches or not. And, 
I tried providing `exact` attribute along with `children` prop but that didn't had any effect. In that scenario also, the children is getting rendered irrespective of location matches or not. I have updated the sandbox with the same.