# What is the different bethween using `children` elements vs using `render` func in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm learning [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) and I don't understand what is the different between using `children` elements in `<Route>` component (not [`children` func](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/children-func) which *appears* to be something different)) vs using `render` prop with inline function.

In other word what is the difference between this code:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/about">
    <About />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/dashboard">
    <Dashboard />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

and

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" render={() => <About />} />
  <Route path="/dashboard" render={() => <Dashboard />} />
</Switch>
```

both code seems to do the [same thing](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-hixgd?file=/example.js)

Which one should I use? What is actual difference in behavior and performance?
In-depth answer would be nice. This is mostly curiosity question. Using `children` elements works fine for me now in my project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React router difference between render and children prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856418/react-router-difference-between-render-and-children-prop)

Comment: @SajadRezvani Not really. I'm just learning this library but I think the other way of asking my question is: "what is the different between using `children` and `render` when you use parent `<Switch/>` component". because they seems to do the same thing: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-y3usy?file=/example.js
The answer you linked shows the difference when there is no parent `<Switch>` component.

Comment: @SajadRezvani Also from the codesandbox example in my previous comment you can see that even without `<Switch>` parent the children *elements* behave the same as render func, but the children *func* behaves differently (as explained in documentation and other answer you linked).
My question is about children *elements* not children *func*.

Answer (score 0):

You have various options to render a component in a route with react-router as explained in the following link.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods

The **key point**, according to the documentation, can be caught in the following sentence, in the "render: func" paragraph.

> This allows for **convenient inline rendering** and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above.

Why do I think that this is the **key point**? Because, if you read carefully each paragraph of the documentation about these render methods, the only reason to use an inline function (using `render` or `children`), is that you don't want to use the `component` prop (maybe because you don't want to create a separate file for that, or for other valid reasons).

My point is also highlighted in the "render: func" code example, here you will find the following code.

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={routeProps => (
    <FadeIn>
      <Component {...routeProps} />
    </FadeIn>
  )}
/>
```

Using the render property, in this case, it avoids you to create a separate file just to wrap the component with `FadeIn`.

So if you have a reason like this, you can use the `render` propery, if not, just use the component property.

Also note that the `component` property will pass the route properties down, as explained in the documentation.

> A React component to render only when the location matches. It will be rendered with route props.

Comment: But my question is what is the difference between using "children elements" (which is preferred way according to [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) ("The recommended method of rendering something with a <Route> is to use children elements, as shown above. ") vs using "render" function.

Comment: Let my try to explain using the same example used in the answer. Using children elements, if you want to have the `FadeIn` as a wrapper, you should change each component used in the various routes (like Home, About and Dashboard) and add the `FadeIn`, with `render` you can keep these components are they are. No need to use render at all if you need to do something like what you did in the question posted.

Comment: I still don't get it. You mostly wrote about `component` vs `render`. I ask about creating routes by providing children *elements* to `<Route>`.
About your `FadeIn` example (`FadingRoute` component from docs). You could also write it using children elements and react router hooks right?

Actually, now I see the docs say that this methods "are provided mostly for supporting apps that were built with earlier versions of the router before hooks were introduced.". So I guess by using children elements and hooks you can do the same thing as you used to do with "render"? Hooks are just never.

Comment: Yes, it is quite rare to use render property in real world, this is why is rare to find examples about that. You may have an example like this `render={routeProps => <MyComponent anExampleProp={routeProps.match.url === "/an/given/url" ? "valueOne" : "valueTwo"} />}` that is not feasible, as it is, with children elements, unless I missed some consideration. In general, we realize that a feature like this is useful only when we have a real world use case. My advice, by the way, is to use render property only if you find a reasonable use case.